# How to pass msg.sender to another function?

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, msg.sender

```
function sell(address useraddress, string memory propertyId) payable public {
        request storage sellingRequest = sellingRequests[propertyId];
        require(!sellingRequest.users[useraddress], "Selling Request already exists");
        request memory buyingRequest = buyingRequests[propertyId];
        if(buyingRequest.exists){
            address payable buyer = buyingRequest.usersaddress[0];
            sendMoney.sendMoneyTo.value(msg.value)(useraddress);
//here I want to pass msg.sender value as buyer
        }
        else{
            sellingRequest.exists = true;
            sellingRequest.users[useraddress] = true;
            address payable seller  = address(uint160(address(useraddress)));
            sellingRequest.usersaddress.push(seller);
        }

    }
```

I am calling another sendMoneyTo function from another contract that accepts address as an argument to send the ether to this address but how can I send the address from whose account the ether should be transferred. I want to send the buyer address here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to make msg.sender the caller of another function inside your sell() function?

Because you can't do that. The msg.sender is calling the sell() function, but if another function is being called inside sell(), the msg.sender will be the contract itself.
Otherwise I could make a contract with harmless looking functions that actually contain

```
erc20.transfer(scammerAddress, allYourToken)
```

and therefore steal all your tokens.
For obvious security reasons, Solidity doesn't let you do that!

You use msg.sender as an argument when calling another function but not as the source of the call

For exemple:

```
erc20.transfer(msg.sender, 1000)
```

will transfer 1000 tokens from the contract address to the msg.sender

Hope this helps!